# How to reduce my server's bandwidth usage?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, bandwidth, video-streaming

I am running a video hosting server using Ubuntu 18.04 with nginx and server's configs are 500gb SSD, 100TB monthly bandwidth and 1gbps network.

I am using nginx amplify to monitor all the traffic, storage and bandwidth usage on my server. I have around 60+ videos on my server and each video is in 480p and the average size of videos are 300-500mb (depending on length of video).

The proper cache is implemented on my nginx server and I am using nginx mp4 module also. I would like to know how can I reduce my server's bandwidth usage because from a month it's going very high and I think it will use the 100TB bandwidth before the month end (14 May) and I will be charged very high per GB cost of every extra bit consumed.

This is my first time running my own media server. If any other info is needed then please let me know.

Comment: Videos are huge! Short of NOT hosting videos there isn't much you can do. Perhaps re-encode them using higher compression (less quality). Where possible embed videos rather than hosting then. As your videos get more popular bandwidth usage will increase.

Comment: Move them to a video streaming service like YouTube, vimeo or equivalent. They are designed to handle this kind of bandwidth.

Comment: That type of content is not allowed on youtube or other video hosting sites so i have no choice instead of using my own server.